# Remove Duplicates from Datatable with LINQ without keeping a duplicated entry at all

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have a `Datatable` with several Columns which I want to remove all duplicates from like that

```
Dt1 = Dt1 .AsEnumerable().GroupBy(r => new { filename = r.Field<string>("filename1"), filesize = r.Field<string>("filesizeinkb") }).Select(g => g.First()).CopyToDataTable();
```

However above code leaves one entry (the first one that is found) in the DataTable via the `Select.First` at the end of the LINQ code.

Is there a way to remove all duplicates and keep none?

**Edit:**
Example what the code is doing now and what it should do.

Datatable with entries like that

| Name | Filesize | Filename |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | 50 | Fileone |
| Two | 50 | Fileone |
| Three | 50 | Filetwo |
| Four | 50 | Filethree |

Above LINQ will now remove Line 2 as Filename and Filesize are the same. However Line 1 will stay as the LINQ Code selects the first duplicated entry.

I want to have removed line 1 and line 2 from the Datatable.

Comment: Maybe try and put your code inside of foreach/for loop?

Comment: Can you provide an example of: 1 - What is the code doing now 2 - What do you want. If you put examples, maybe I can help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```cs
Dt1 = Dt1.AsEnumerable()
         .GroupBy(r => new { filename = r.Field<string>("filename1"), filesize = r.Field<string>("filesizeinkb") })
         .Where(g => g.Count() == 1)
         .Select(g => g.First())
         .CopyToDataTable();
```

That will discard any groups with more than one item, then get the first (and only) item from the rest.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** This was blindly typed here, so there might be some typos in the code.

Idea is, get the number of rows inside your `DataTable`, and go trough each of them, and do what you already did.

```
int NumOfItems = Dt1.AsEnumarable().ToList();

for(int i = 0; i < NumOfItems.Count; i++)
{
   Dt1 = Dt1 .AsEnumerable().GroupBy(r => new { filename = r.Field<string>("filename1"), filesize = r.Field<string>("filesizeinkb") }).Select(g => g.First()).CopyToDataTable();
}
```

Comment: `First` is fine and, indeed, preferable in this instance because every group must contain at least one item. If there were no items to put in that group then there wouldn't be a group.

Comment: @John Oh, ‍♂️, my bad. You're right.